# rpm dependency to a running kerenl version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rpm, kernel-module

I'm building an RPM that contain a kernel module.
Like all the other kernel modules, there is a dependency between the running kernel version to the kernel module.
I want to enforce this dependency, so if you want to update your kernel, you will need to update my rpm.
I was trying to do that with the spec file but without success. 
Could you help me to find a way to do this?
Any other idea for enforce update of my kernel module during kernel update?

Comment: Have you tried something like `requires: kernel = exact-version-of-kernel` in the spec-file?

Comment: Yap, but it's checking if i have rpm of this kernel, not if it is the running kernel during the installation.

Comment: You don't need to care if it is the running kernel, not really. You can't have RPM assert that for you anyway. You could use the kernel's weak-module support to get your module to be "forward-linked" to newer kernels that are compatible though if that helps any.